# org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException in WAS9 server

Tags: java, spring, websphere, cxf

Can you please help me with following error I'm facing in WAS9 environment:

In order to resolve the import

`org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapHeader`

I added the following dependencies in my pom.xml:

`cxf-api-2.7.7
cxf-rt-bindings-soap-2.7.7`

But when I'm trying to run my application, I'm getting the following error.

```
Default Executor-thread-7] ([  ])  Controllerclass - org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException
at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.load(Extension.java:222)
at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl.loadAndRegister(ExtensionManagerImpl.java:199)
at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl.initialize(ExtensionManagerImpl.java:118)
at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerBus.doInitializeInternal(ExtensionManagerBus.java:147)
at org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusImpl.initialize(CXFBusImpl.java:191)
at com.ibm.ws.jaxws.bus.LibertyApplicationBusFactory.createBus(LibertyApplicationBusFactory.java:119)
at com.ibm.ws.jaxws.bus.LibertyApplicationBusFactory.createClientScopedBus(LibertyApplicationBusFactory.java:86)
at com.ibm.ws.jaxws.metadata.JaxWsClientMetaData.<init>(JaxWsClientMetaData.java:28)
at com.ibm.ws.jaxws.metadata.JaxWsModuleMetaData.getClientMetaData(JaxWsModuleMetaData.java:123)
at com.ibm.ws.jaxws.support.JaxWsMetaDataManager.getJaxWsClientMetaData(JaxWsMetaDataManager.java:84)
at com.ibm.ws.jaxws.support.JaxWsMetaDataManager.getJaxWsClientMetaData(JaxWsMetaDataManager.java:123)
at com.ibm.ws.jaxws.client.LibertyProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(LibertyProviderImpl.java:56)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:57)

Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException:org.apache.cxf.bus.osgi.OSGIBusListener
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.load(Extension.java:218)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:org.apache.cxf.bus.osgi.OSGIBusListener.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
```

Answer (score 1):

The server where your WAS9 has been deployed has different version of the above jar file. You need to have same version of jar files both in your eclipse where you have developed your codes and the server where you are deploying the `war` or `ear`.

mavan dependency file pom.xml is used during your project compilation. It might add the jar in your binary under lib folder as well. But WAS9 might considering the one which is in server's CLASSPATH. Hence check your class path and replace that jar with the one which you have mentioned in your pom.xml file. Hope that will fix your issue.

Comment: Thankyou for your response, I will check on that and let you know.

Comment: Hello Abhijit , I tried by replacing cxf jars in war file (WEBINF/LIB) with jars in WAS9 (wlp/lib), still getting same issue, got stuck with this issue any help would be greatful., also Iam trying to change  <classloader delegation="parentLast"/> , but this one is not working properly inside <webApplication> tags, when I tried to modify <webApplication> tag to <application> server is starting but failing to bring up my war file and giving below error.

Comment: Stack Dump = com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.StateChangeException: com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.StateChangeException: startWebApplication

Comment: Also I tried by adding   <scope>provided</scope> in my pom.xml to eliminate that binaries from war file at run time, and war build without any cxf jars, but this didn't helped me to resolve the problem

Answer (score 1):

We can eliminate this exception by adding webProfile-7.0 in our server.xml, but how ever this is not working with javaee-7.0 not sure, if one knows about how to handle this in javaee-7.0 please share your approach.

Comment: I got the same error too. Removed javaee-7.0 and leaving webProfile-7.0 got be going. Hope they fix it, so I can use Cxf and ejb together.